# Powershell, RunAs vs Credential

Tags: powershell

So I have not found anything that explains why this code will run when you open PowerShell as "Administrator", entering your domain admin credential. Whereas when you open PowerShell with no admin privilege and using the `-credential Domain\DomainAdminUser`, then entering your password when prompted and I get error. Why is this?

> Error: Get-WinEvent: The parameter is incorrect.

I'm asking because I have a menu script which I can run it as admin using my domain admin credential but the `gpresult` command will not work because of "invalid pointer" and reason being is, my domain account is not part of the authenticated user.

So to make it easy, I need to run my menu script without admin rights and use the `-credential` switch for certain commands within the menu script.

```
cls
$logname = "Security"
$Id = "4634"
$Id2 = "4624"             
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential Domain\DomainAdminuser @{logname=$logname;Id=$Id,$Id2;starttime=[datetime]::Today} | 
Select-Object TimeCreated, Id, @{n="Message";e={($_.message).Split(" ")[0..4] -join " "}} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: Thanks James. I'll be sure to carefully edit my post next time before posting.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but elevation ("Run as administrator") is not the same as being a member of a group.

Comment: Right, but it still doesn't explain why the script will not run when I use -credential. I have to delete -credential part and run my menu script with elevated rights (DA) and then it works.

Comment: Specifying credentials `-ne` elevation (this is particularly true and noticeable on the current computer).

Comment: Can you provide examples what I can put for the value expression after -ne ?

Comment: What I meant was, "specifying credentials is not the same thing as elevation."